# Reading a text file in Java upto an empty line

Tags: java, list

Reading a text file of the following  format:

```
line1
line2

line3
line4
```

Use case is to append the first two line into a list, the last 2 lines into another list and finally append both the list to a list of lists.

Code:

```
public static void readUI() {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath2));
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> checkList = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        String[] splitline;
        String[] subSplit;

        //populating the first list
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                list.add(line.trim());
            } else {
                checkList.add(list);
                list.clear();
            }

        }
        //System.out.println(checkList);
        //System.out.println(checkList.get(0));
        //System.out.println(checkList.get(1));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("OOPS! File could not read!");
    }

}
```

Logic explained:

Read the lines from the file keep appending it to list, when I encounter a empty line append the list to a list of lists and clear the single list.

Error:

It is getting appended to the list of lists as one single list and not 2 single lists.

Any suggestions on how to correct it?

Comment: It would be simple if you add a counter and use nested list. Increment counter value when code encounters a blank space and start putting data into next list. In the end write a loop and club all the lists.

Comment: That while loop can be replaced by `br.lines().forEach(line ->{...})` Also, every time you clear the list, you clear the list you added to checkList as they are the same object.

Comment: Do you have a blank line at the end of the file? if not the second list will never get added to the `checkList`

Comment: @JerinJoseph nope I made sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the below code after the end of while loop

`if(list.size() > 0){
    checkList.add(list);
}`

This would ensure the second (or last) list will get added to the checkList.

Comment: It is working now. But could you please comment on the mistake I was doing.

Comment: When the second list is populated, it would not go into the while loop as the `((line = br.readLine()) != null)` condition would fail when the end-of-file is encountered.  And hence it does not get added to the checkList.  So, you need to add it separately after the while loop.

Comment: Thank you. Got it!

Answer (score 2):

You never create a new list when you reach a new line. Instead, you're adding the list to another list, then clearing it.

Instead of calling `list.clear()` you need do reassign it by using `list = new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public static void readUI() {
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath2)) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        List<List<String>> checkList = new ArrayList<>();

        br.lines().forEach(line -> {
           if(line.trim().isEmpty())){
               checkList.add(list);
               list = new ArrayList();
           } else {
               list.add(line);
           }
        });

        if(!list.isEmpty()){
            checkList.add(list);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("OOPS! File could not read!");
    }
}
```